# Как растянуть background на всю форму? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Вставляю background на форму, остаются внешние отступы, в параметрах не нашел ничего с этим связанного. Как убрать эти самые отступы?

Вот сам код:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="launcher.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:launcher"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="850"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="850">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="background.png" AlignmentX="Center"></ImageBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Что получается по итогу...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что [не воспроизводится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19ueA.jpg). Теперь давайте гадать.... 1. Вы у окна убрали стиль, включили поддержку прозрачности, но, само окно по умолчанию, имеет белый `Background`, вы его почему не убрали? 2. Не задавайте размеры контенту, делайте его динамичным, пусть сам выбирает, какой ему размер выбрать! 3. Если в вопросе весь код, то скорей всего, ваша картинка меньше, чем `Height="500" Width="850"`.

Comment: Почему бы такую рамочку с помощью `Border` не сделать? И `Grid` занимает по умолчанию все доступное место, его не надо настраивать для этого. Настраивайте картинку.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо...

Comment: За что? Я вам дал наводящие вопросы и решения, на которые вы не дали ответа и не помогли нам решить проблему. За что спасибо то? Если нашли решение, то опубликуйте его в виде ответа!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: Stretch="None" в параметрах картинки.