# ProgressBar с закругленными краями

Tags: c#, wpf

Как нарисовать такую панель в WPF?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Битый час сижу кручу эллипсы, еще что-то, в wpf 1-й проект, до этого Win Application использовал, древняя вещь.

 Буду очень благодарен!

Визуальная часть

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="0,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="361" >
                <Border Background="#282727" BorderBrush="#282727" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="35,10,0,0" Width="305">
                    <Border Background="#68C73E" BorderBrush="#68C73E" CornerRadius="10"  BorderThickness="0" Margin="228,-9,16,42" Width="55" Height="14"/>

                </Border>

            </StackPanel>
            <Image>
                <Image.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="1">

                    </BlurEffect>
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>
            <Label Content="ВЫБРАНО" Margin="266,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Exo 2.0"/>

            <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar1" Value="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8" Margin="45,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" Style="{DynamicResource CornerRadius}"/>
            <Image Name="PointOnline1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="313,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16" Source="ellipse.png" Stretch="None" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Image.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="1"></BlurEffect>
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>
            <Label Content="Игроков онлайн: {%d}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Exo 2.0"/>
```

Comment: Во-первых, разберитесь со старыми вопросами, писать комментарии в пустоту, лично мне, надоело. Поймите, это не форум, где вы чатитесь с людьми, а база вопросов и ответов на них! Приносите пользу обществу и общество будет приносить пользу вам! Во-вторых, где ваши попытки? Не уж то трудно сделать `StackPanel` или `Grid`, где будут размещены 3 контрола (`TextBlock` в `Border`, просто `TextBlock`, ну и `Slider` (или `ProgressBar`)) с нужными стилями?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не трудно, пробовал, но там конфликтуют между собой гриды, сдвигают друг друга, не знаю что делать с ними. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Я вам задавал уже вопросы, на которые так и не получил ответ. Не ставьте статичные размеры объектам, не используйте дизайнер для создания UI, и почему `DockPanel`? Вот если бы вы это все послушали и хоть как-то среагировали, то наверно уже бы научились чему-то. Но вы продолжаете в пустую задавать вопросы, даже не принимаете ответы, которые для вам старательно подготавливают другие участники... Также, еще раз повторю `где ваши попытки?`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ касаемо панельки - вот:

`<Grid Name="ListOfServers" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="332">
                    
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="500"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>`

Comment: `Width="332"`, `Width="500"`, `Не ставьте статичные размеры объектам`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я самоучка, не стоит говорить что я не учусь и использую готовое и между прочем, к большей части советов я прислушивался и что-либо применял. Стоит учитывать такие моменты, когда применяя одно, изменений может потребовать другое. (TDD - Test Driven Development)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а как лучше ставить? У меня просто панель фиксированного размера и она расплывется без этого. И плюс ко всему, получается в этом Row должно быть 2 Column, слева одни панельки, справа другие

Comment: Я вижу, как вы учитесь. [2 дня](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186279#comment2066107_1186279) прошло с моего комментария (и [день](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186966#comment2067516_1186966) с другого), который вы благополучно проигнорировали. Также, там вам дали ответ на "Как надо", который вы тоже благополучно проигнорировали. Научитесь пользоваться сеткой, дайте волю объектам, пусть они сами подставиваются под нужный размер.

Comment: Эллипсы здесь не нужны, нужен `Border` с закругленными краями, вроде `CornerRadius` задает. И обрезкой контента внутри него, по-моему `ClipToBounds`.

Comment: @aepot Вы что обрезать тут решили?) Простой `Border` с закруглением и нужным цветом и контент внутри с отступом, вот и все, за края там не выходит что-либо. Помниться [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076429/220553) однажды на один вопрос, там был простой стиль для `ProgressBar` с закруглением, и вот этого достаточно для решения данной задачи. Только вот автор вопроса до сих пор не хочет понимать, как позиционировать объекты в WPF, много лишнего пишет, не показывая это нам, увы...

Comment: @aepot визуальную часть сделал, код закрепил. Осталось с кругом разобраться, что бы двигался в соотношении с значением прогресс бара. У меня была идея сделать что-то такое: `ВзятьЗначениеКругаПоОсиX = ЗначениеПрогрессБара`
Данный способ не идеал и даже не правильный, но лучше чем ничего)
Посмотрел, есть метод RenderTransform, но он не совсем то, что нужно наверное..

Comment: Мдя, слушать вы явно не хотите. Говорю, чтоб не использовали дизайнер для создания UI, что он генерирует много лишнего, но нет, и так (`Margin="228,-9,16,42" Width="55" Height="14"`) сойдет, да? Чтож, ваше дело, не спрашивайте потом, почему у вас нету какого-либо объекта, все плывет и так далее.

Comment: Не надо белый круг, выглядит плохо, похоже не на прогресс, а на регулируемый ползунок. Сделайте просто без круга.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше пишите xaml руками, а не используйте визуальный дизайнер. В таком случае, вам не придется воевать с марджинами, а интерфейс будет более аккуратный и отзывчивый на изменение размеров окна. Используйте где можно относительное позиционирование и выравнивание, избегайте абсолютных величин в пикселях для перемещения контролов на большие расстояния.

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="20" Background="#222222" Margin="0,8,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" >
            <TextBlock Text="Игроков онлайн: 412" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
            <Grid Margin="0,5">
                <Border x:Name="MaskBorder" CornerRadius="5" Background="Black" Height="10"/>
                <ProgressBar Value="40" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.001" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="LawnGreen">
                    <ProgressBar.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="LawnGreen" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="20"/>
                    </ProgressBar.Effect>
                    <ProgressBar.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MaskBorder}"/>
                    </ProgressBar.OpacityMask>
                </ProgressBar>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0" Background="LawnGreen">
        <TextBlock Text="ВЫБРАНО" Padding="3,1"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076429/220553) есть еще один вариант решения с использованием `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Зря заголовок поменяли вопроса. Теперь его можно расценивать как дубликат, ибо вопросов по закруглению `ProgressBar` на SO есть несколько (один я уже вам кидал). Тут больше вопрос про создание такой структуры, а не про `ProgressBar`. Также стоило бы расписать человеку как позиционировать объекты в WPF, ибо это его основная проблема и каждый вопрос связан с этим (предположу, что и следующие тоже будут связаны с проблемой позиционирования). Ну и `OpacityMask` тут не нужен.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я не нашел дубликата на RU SO по вопросам, содержащим "ProgressBar" в заголовке, поэтому и поменял заголовок. По поводу расписать, я и так показал почти готовый xaml, в котором все позиционируется как надо. Думаю, рано или поздно автор разберется с этим сам, но я добавил немного пояснений.

Comment: Я вам кидал [ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076429/220553), вот чем не дубликат? Создание закругленного `ProgressBar`, то, какой вы заголовок поставили. А по поводу "я и так показал почти готовый xaml" - судя по тому, что вы написали предыдущий ответ, но автор даже не вник что там и как, я думаю, этого мало...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там через `ControlTemplate`. И там `progress bar`, а не `ProgressBar`, и там про свечение, а не про закругляхи. С точки зрения поиска - оно разное. Видимо, поэтому я и не нашел.

Comment: А для дубликата имеет разницу, как решена задача? Нет. Поэтому давайте все же определим, этот вопрос про "ProgressBar с закругленными краями", или "Как нарисовать такую панель в WPF?", если первое, то я буду голосовать за дубликат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ делайте, как считаете правильным, я только за, если свяжем этот вопрос с тем решением, они действительно схожие.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ оставили бы хотя-бы слово ProgressBar в заголовке, а то теперь этот вопрос вообще вряд-ли кто-то найдет. :) Еще я удивился, что вопрос пропал из ленты, оказывается вы просто c# тег удалили, я кстати не трекаю, ни wpf, не xaml.

Comment: А как он относится к вопросу? На скрине вообще `Slider`, судя по кругляшку. Тут именно вопрос про создание панели, а на месте всех этих объектов может быть что угодно, хоть просто `Border` с нужным цветом. Там и слова нет про то, как сделать закругленный `ProgressBar`. Также C# убрал, ибо вопрос про XAML и WPF. Я кстати проверил тот код, что у автора в вопрсое, там нормальная панель отображается, проблема только в том, что он поставил `Margin` и размеры статичные (о чем я уже 2 дня говорю), так что, правильней было бы объяснить его ошибки, а не писать по новой, делаяя акцент на `ProgressBar`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нет предела совершенству, и времени тоже нет. Прошу меня извинить.

Comment: Ну к вам у меня претензий нету, кроме заголовка про `ProgressBar`, из-за которого вопрос можно было бы закрывать как дубликат. Вы дали хороший (хоть и костыльный) ответ, жаль только автору это мало чем поможет. Я лишь обосновал свое видение данного вопроса, и думаю, что вы согласны с тем, что я написал выше, а если нет, то можете отредактировать вопрос так, как желаете.  Я за чистоту SO и как по мне, таким этот вопрос должен был быть изначально.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так и надо было закрывать как дубликат. В этом нет ничего страшного. Ну уже это все не важно, вопрос уже отвечен, и ответ принят.

Comment: Ну так это не дубликат. Тут нету вопроса про `ProgressBar`. Это вы почему-то написали в заголовке и сделали акцент именно на `ProgressBar`, а не на создание панели. Сам же вопрос тут про позиционирование объектов, чтоб получить именно такую панельку, как на скрине. По этому тут вряд-ли кто либо проголосовал за дубликат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть, он в xaml вопроса сидит, спрятался. А то что он на скриншоте выглядит как слайдер - это видимо проблема дизайна.

Comment: В коде что угодно может быть. Сам вопрос `Как нарисовать такую панель в WPF?`, это по вашему равноценно `ProgressBar с закругленными краями`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в данном случае, не равноценно, а второе даже точнее отражает суть вопроса. Но это всего-лишь мое мнение. Может быть я и ошибся. Кажется, автор уже решил этот вопрос уже без нас. :)

Comment: Я спросил в чате у людей, как правильней тут поступить. Посмотрим, что скажут.