# Как обрезать canvas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Необходимо обрезать фигуру. Нужно сделать прозрачную обводку вокруг зеленого кружочка.

Вот как есть:

[image: как есть]

А этом изображении я просто залил Stroke цветом фона. Но так не красиво и работать так как мне надо не будет:

[image: нужно так]

Код XAML:

```xml
<Canvas MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="50" MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="50">
    <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="{Binding ContactPhoto, FallbackValue='C://Program Files (x86)/LawChat/userdata/Images/no_photo.jpg', TargetNullValue='C://Program Files (x86)/LawChat/userdata/Images/no_photo.jpg'}"/>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Margin="40,35,0,0" StrokeThickness="3" Width="15" Height="15">
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Chartreuse"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF21242A"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
    </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Не понял, что вам надо. Маски отображения есть. Наложив маску на объект можно вырезать таким образом в нём дырку.

Comment: Нужно сделать обводку зеленого кружечка так, что бы он прошивал основной большой кружочек на сквозь. Я не знаю как по другому это объяснить =)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1187535/373567 `OpacityMask`

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем понимаю как это относится к моему вопросу. Куда рыть? Мне нужно что то со Stroke сделать?

Comment: я создал еще один элемент снизу  зеленого кружочка  большего его в диаметре и попытался убрать его через опасити маск. Не получается...

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вам надо обводку рисовать на альфа-канале (прозрачности)

Comment: @user7860670 о чем вы?

Comment: Вы спросили, как вырезать дырку в контроле - я ответил: с помощью `OpacityMask` и пример использования показал. Осталось создать визуал, который выглядит по контуру как надо, и применить его как маску по нужным вам условиям. Я не знаю, как здесь еще помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

От части, тут все просто, но не совсем...

В WPF особо нет чего либо, что может взять и "вырезать" часть из другой части, такое поведение есть например в `GeometryGroup`, которое используется в `Path`, но там вы рисуете фигурами, примитивами, а не картинками и чем либо еще. В связи с этим, вам изначально нужен некий "референс", некий "макет", который будет подходить задавать вид вашей картинке при помощи `OpacityMask` - инструмента, который позволяет отображать лишь заданную часть, а все остальное скрывать. В качестве маски, советую использовать вектор, который можете сгенерировать без проблем из картинки при помощи онлайн инструментов, либо [офлайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869660/220553).

Как сделал я:

1. Нарисовал в первом попавшемся [онлайн фотошопе](https://online-photoshop.org/edit/) изображение, взял просто круг, и вырезал из него другой круг, убрал фон, и сохранил в .PNG, получил такое:

   [image]

   Изображение большевато (500х500), думаю без проблем 100х100 подошло бы, но не суть..
2. Написал в гугле "png to svg", и нашел первой ссылкой [онлайн конвертор](https://convertio.co/ru/png-svg/), загрузил туда изображение, и скачал получившийся `.svg`:

   ```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
    <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="500.000000pt" height="500.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 500.000000 500.000000"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

    <g transform="translate(0.000000,500.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
    fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M2265 4989 c-419 -43 -797 -177 -1143 -405 -146 -96 -220 -155 -354
    -283 -408 -389 -669 -909 -749 -1491 -17 -124 -17 -496 0 -620 102 -740 497
    -1376 1102 -1774 682 -448 1509 -538 2279 -248 58 21 140 57 182 78 l77 39
    -40 60 c-102 155 -142 366 -104 550 32 153 97 274 207 383 99 100 219 167 358
    203 72 18 268 18 340 0 77 -20 186 -67 245 -107 l50 -34 52 108 c96 197 179
    486 214 742 17 124 17 496 0 620 -102 739 -497 1376 -1101 1773 -355 233 -724
    363 -1159 407 -118 12 -339 11 -456 -1z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
   ```
3. Все в том-же поисковике, написал "optimize svg", и все аналогично, первой ссылкой нашел [оптимизатор SVG](https://svgoptimizer.com/), в который закинул файл, и скачал исходный вариант, который похудел на 32%. Этот шаг я сделал не ради размера, а больше ради того, чтоб за меня убрали переходы на новую строку, которые в данном случае не нужны, в итоге файл получился таким:

   ```xml
    <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="666.667" height="666.667" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path d="M226.5 1.1c-41.9 4.3-79.7 17.7-114.3 40.5-14.6 9.6-22 15.5-35.4 28.3C36 108.8 9.9 160.8 1.9 219c-1.7 12.4-1.7 49.6 0 62 10.2 74 49.7 137.6 110.2 177.4 68.2 44.8 150.9 53.8 227.9 24.8 5.8-2.1 14-5.7 18.2-7.8l7.7-3.9-4-6c-10.2-15.5-14.2-36.6-10.4-55 3.2-15.3 9.7-27.4 20.7-38.3 9.9-10 21.9-16.7 35.8-20.3 7.2-1.8 26.8-1.8 34 0 7.7 2 18.6 6.7 24.5 10.7l5 3.4 5.2-10.8c9.6-19.7 17.9-48.6 21.4-74.2 1.7-12.4 1.7-49.6 0-62C487.9 145.1 448.4 81.4 388 41.7 352.5 18.4 315.6 5.4 272.1 1c-11.8-1.2-33.9-1.1-45.6.1z"/></svg>
   ```
4. Открываем студию, и пишем XAML. Нам нужна строго квадратная панель, в которой будет картинка, растягивающаяся до максимума, и в нижнем правом углу кружочек:

   ```xml
    <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
        <Image
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Source="https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/529/871/HD-wallpaper-the-wandering-earth-2-movie-poster.jpg"
                Stretch="UniformToFill">
        </Image>
        <Ellipse
                Width="27"
                Height="27"
                Margin="0,0,1,1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Fill="#FF108E10"/>
    </Grid>
   ```

   Результатом будет такое:

   [image: Result]

   Обратите внимание, я использую правильное позиционирование, у меня "статус онлайна" сразу находится в нижнем правом углу, от которого я делаю отступ всего на 1 пункт, у меня нет таких бешенных значений как у вас в `Margin`. Мой совет, забудьте про позиционирование элементов отступами, это неверно, и чревато огромными проблемами!
5. Теперь маска, при помощи которой превращаем квадрат в круг. Маску применяем картинке, задав ей `<Image.OpacityMask>`, сам тип маски `VisualBrush` со свойством `Stretch="Uniform"`, внутри делаем `Viewbox` для автоматического подгона размеров вектора под размеры картинки, ну а внутри делаем `Canvas` фиксированного размера, на котором рисуем через `Path` сам вектор, где свойство `Data`, это самое длинное значение из .svg файла, зовется которое `d`. Получаем в итоге такую разметку:

   ```xml
    <Image
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Source="https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/529/871/HD-wallpaper-the-wandering-earth-2-movie-poster.jpg"
        Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                            <Path Data="M226.5 1.1c-41.9 4.3-79.7 17.7-114.3 40.5-14.6 9.6-22 15.5-35.4 28.3C36 108.8 9.9 160.8 1.9 219c-1.7 12.4-1.7 49.6 0 62 10.2 74 49.7 137.6 110.2 177.4 68.2 44.8 150.9 53.8 227.9 24.8 5.8-2.1 14-5.7 18.2-7.8l7.7-3.9-4-6c-10.2-15.5-14.2-36.6-10.4-55 3.2-15.3 9.7-27.4 20.7-38.3 9.9-10 21.9-16.7 35.8-20.3 7.2-1.8 26.8-1.8 34 0 7.7 2 18.6 6.7 24.5 10.7l5 3.4 5.2-10.8c9.6-19.7 17.9-48.6 21.4-74.2 1.7-12.4 1.7-49.6 0-62C487.9 145.1 448.4 81.4 388 41.7 352.5 18.4 315.6 5.4 272.1 1c-11.8-1.2-33.9-1.1-45.6.1z" Fill="Black" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
   ```

   Ну а результатом будет такое:

   [image: Final Result]
6. Финальный штрих, все полученное, загоняем в `ViewBox`, чтобы все подгонялось под размеры родителя, без потерь позиционирования, получив в финале такую разметку:

   ```xml
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Image
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Source="https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/529/871/HD-wallpaper-the-wandering-earth-2-movie-poster.jpg"
            Stretch="UniformToFill">
                <Image.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Viewbox>
                                <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                                    <Path Data="M226.5 1.1c-41.9 4.3-79.7 17.7-114.3 40.5-14.6 9.6-22 15.5-35.4 28.3C36 108.8 9.9 160.8 1.9 219c-1.7 12.4-1.7 49.6 0 62 10.2 74 49.7 137.6 110.2 177.4 68.2 44.8 150.9 53.8 227.9 24.8 5.8-2.1 14-5.7 18.2-7.8l7.7-3.9-4-6c-10.2-15.5-14.2-36.6-10.4-55 3.2-15.3 9.7-27.4 20.7-38.3 9.9-10 21.9-16.7 35.8-20.3 7.2-1.8 26.8-1.8 34 0 7.7 2 18.6 6.7 24.5 10.7l5 3.4 5.2-10.8c9.6-19.7 17.9-48.6 21.4-74.2 1.7-12.4 1.7-49.6 0-62C487.9 145.1 448.4 81.4 388 41.7 352.5 18.4 315.6 5.4 272.1 1c-11.8-1.2-33.9-1.1-45.6.1z" Fill="Black" />
                                </Canvas>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Image.OpacityMask>
            </Image>
            <Ellipse
            Width="27"
            Height="27"
            Margin="0,0,1,1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Fill="#FF108E10" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
   ```

   И как видите, все успешно подстроилось под размеры окна

   [image: Window Result]

Вот и все, вам остается лишь нарисовать более грамотный вектор (под свой вкус), сделать из этого отдельный контрол, и встроить его простым `<control:UserImage Image=".." Status = "..." />` (названия на бум) в нужное место. Удачи!

А да, может возникнуть вопрос, почему мы сетке задаем строго статичные размеры (`<Grid Width="100" Height="100">`), ответ прост - Нам надо, чтобы у нас был ровный квадрат, под который `Image` подгонит изображение любого размера. Если у нас не будет этого, то например указав прямоугольное изображение, кружок статуса уйдет в сторону, ибо `Grid` автоматически расширится под самый большой объект, изображение. Вот чтоб этого не был, нам нужен строго статичный объект, который уже потом растягиваем при помощи `ViewBox` под нужный нам размер.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень благодарю за подробность и потраченное время!